# sifrai halacha on gittin

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, divorce

Most botai din today are mainly involved with gittin. That is something one has to use them for. How do they go about learning it. Which sefer do they mainly use. I am mainly looking for some modern sefer who has gone through all the others like the MB did for orach chaim.

Just learning the Shulchan aruch wont get you very far even with its main meforshim. 
I would also like to know if anyone can add to my list of prewar mefarshim (below) on the shulchan aruch or have an index to it. These are mainly downloaded and printed from hebrew books. I believe in having everything possible in front of me when learning.

- טיב גיטין
- כרם שלמה
- מחשבת הקודש,
- שבילי תורה,
- גט פשוט,
- נודע בשערים,
- דרישת ארי,
- זקן שמואל,
- מחצית השקל,
- ראש פינה,
- אבני מילואים,
- תורת גיטין
- ערוך השולחן
- חזון איש
- שדה אליהו,
- לבוש,
- יד אהרן,
- כנסת הגדולה,
- ישועות יעקב,
- שמן למאור,
- גט מקושר,
- ברכת המים
- מכתב מאליהו,
- אהלי שם
- ביאור מנחם

Comment: I would add that there are really more since many seforim are called tiv gittin and many called get mekushar. It does confuse one by being called the same name but most likely they never saw each other.

Comment: Like learning magen avrohom is impossible without the machtsis hashekel the same is with the bais shemual who lived about the same time as the MGA and wrote in the same style. It is only today that two seforim which I have mentioned above, have been printed, (the other being rosh pinah) both written pre-war, that fully explain the bais shmuel.

Comment: There are many more printed in todays shulchan aruch but I have not mentioned them. The latest printed shulchan aruch  is by machon rosh pinah with two volumes on gittin which will set you back a hundred dollars. The machtsis hashekel and rosh pinah which are really necessary come in sets which is another 100 dollars. Almost all the rest one can get from hebrew books. As long as you know how to refill a laser printer it shouldnt cost you much.

Comment: I shall add to the list if I find more like I have just done.

Comment: http://www.halachabrura.org/library/library8d.htm#אהעז  There are many more here and it will take me some time to find the ones directly on the shulchan aruch. דברי אליעזר, תפארת יעקב So far.

Comment: There are basically two 'branches' of gittin each with their own seforim. One on the practical aspect of giving a get and the other on names. Names where there are more than one like today where one has a Jewish and non Jewish one are very complicated especially for women whose Jewish name is never used. As far as I can see having been given a name at birth which is subsequently never used should not be written in a kesuba or get and if it is, it makes it pasul. The main sefer on names is surprisingly from the kitsur called 'ohoalai shem' and written in the same style.

Answer (score 3):

A recent sefer called *Shulchan Ha'even* by Rabbi Zabrowski is similar to a mishne brurah style sefer.

Comment: thank you. http://zbermanbooks.com/product-19671.html But it doesnt seem to be available.